# Menu Toggle Breaks everything when in xs.

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When I get to the xs (Phone version) and press the Toggle Menu button it breaks the whole layout and the carousel rides on top of everything.

This is the Simple Sidebar 
          Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template

```
    <body>

       <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">RFA</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">BIO</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Cadre</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Store</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Conferences</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!-- Page Content -->
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
                      <h1 class="col-xs-12">Robin Fogarty and Associates</h1>
                      <img src="images/RFA_circles.png" alt="RFA" class="img-responsive rfa" title="Robin Fogarty and Associates">
                      <p>For the past 15 years Robin Fogarty and Associates has been a publisher and leading experts on staff development design for Skylight Publishing .</p>
                      <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active">                                    </li>
            <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active"><img src="images/Rote&Spatial_color.png" alt="First slide image" class="center-block">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>First slide Heading</h3>
                <p>First slide Caption</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><img src="images/WalikingwithDaisy_color.png" alt="Second slide image" class="center-block">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Second slide Heading</h3>
                <p>Second slide Caption</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item"><img src="images/Poster.png" alt="Third slide image" class="center-block">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Third slide Heading</h3>
                <p>Third slide Caption</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></div>




        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->


    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <!-- <script src="js/jquery.js"></script> -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Made me strip a lot of the  code so I hope the is enough.

Comment: If you could put a live example up on a site like codepen or jsfiddle I could try and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your carousel in a row, apply this CSS

```
.carousel-wrap{
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/wKXEpX)